# Can I open a MS access mdb file on CD with Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-access

Due to the MS Access database file generating a .ldb lock file when the .mdb file is open I get error trying running a Delphi application on CD where the database file also is on the CD.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Copy it to the user's TEMP folder and open it!? :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. You need to specify that you're opening the database in read-only mode. You didn't specify how you are opening the Access database, but for example, if you were using the ADODB COM objects, you would do something like this your your ADODB Connection object:

```
    conn.Provider := 'Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0';
    conn.Mode := adShareDenyWrite;
    conn.Open('database.mdb');
```

Or within the connection string itself:

```
    conn.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;' + 
        'Data Source=database.mdb;' +
        'Mode=Share Deny Write';
    conn.Open;
```

Comment: adModeShareDenyWrite prevents others from opening a connection with write permissions; doesn't make the current session's connection read-only.  Is adoShareDenyWrite some Delphi-specific constant which has a different meaning?

Comment: +1, [Must Open MDB on Read-Only Media with adShareDenyWrite](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195475)

Comment: @Hansup - that's the name of the constant value in the ADODB documentation (well, the 'ado' was a typo, it's 'adShareDenyWrite'); depending on which ADO Framework you pick they'll probably have different names. I'd probably just go with the connection string option anyway.